# Security cookies ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies

I've a code to persist information in cookies about users like UserName and password.

Question is:

Its not secure to store information like that plain text in cookies.My DB store hashed passwords,so i could save those hashs in cookies and retrieve them later,but if i do that i wouldnt be able to fill password's textbox cause the hash string would be too long for it.

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never should store Passwords in plain text, and even a hashed password can be vulnerable to reverse-lookup unless it is salted correctly. ASP.NET Forms Authentication already lets you create a Persistent authentication cookie that will allow the user to stay logged in, so you should use that instead. See the Timeout, expires, and IsPersistant properties when [Creating the Forms Authentication Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx).

Alternatively you could setup a [token based authentication](http://developergeeks.com/article/18/introduction-to-token-based-authentication) system, by which users get a security token after they enter their login information and this token is valid for a specified amount of time. This is how Live ID and Google Accounts work, and they usually store the tolken in a cookie that is valid for weeks at a time.